# Convergence of $\sum_n \frac{(a_n)^2}{100}$ where $\lim a_n = 0.01$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to show that$\sum_n \frac{(a_n)^2}{100}$ s.t $\lim a_n = 0.01$ diverges while I feel it converges because when $n$ is large, $\frac{(a_n)^2}{100}$ get closer to $0.01$. So I thought the summation is bounded above. How can I show it's divergent?

Comment: The terms don't go to $0$ (though they do not approach $.01$)..

Comment: The necessary condition for convergence is that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$, the limit of the $n^{th}$ term in this case is not 0, so the series diverges

Comment: You are confused by the limits of the sum versus the limits of the summands. Let $a_n=0.01$, then you have a sum of constant positive values which obviously diverge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A necessary condition for the series to converge would be
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_n^2}{100}=0.$$ You can see this, as the sequence of partial sums needs to be a Cauchy sequence, if the series converges.
That implies for $\varepsilon>0$ there exist $N\in\mathbb{N}$ so that for all $n\geq N$ one has
$$\frac{a_{n+1}^2}{100}=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{a_k^2}{100}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{a_k^2}{100}<\varepsilon.$$
This would imply $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=0.$